# How do I print a substring?

Tags: lua

```
function read_file(file)
data = io.open(file, "r")
for char in data:lines() do
    if char == "print>" then
        print(string.sub(char, 6))
    end
end
data:close()
end

function run()
while true do
    print("Open a file")
    file = io.read()
    print("")
    read_file(file)
    print("")
end
end

run()
```

> The code "if char == "print>" then print(string.sub(char, 6)) end" will show me nothing, I have tried to fix this I even looked it up but no luck, any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: `if char:sub(1,6) == "print>" then print(char:sub(7)) end`

Answer (score 2):

You should use [`string.match`](https://devdocs.io/lua/index#pdf-string.match) and/or [`string.sub`](https://devdocs.io/lua/index#pdf-string.sub).

All the following solutions would work:

```
if char:match "^print>" then print( char:sub(7) ) end
```

or

```
local d = char:match "^print>(.+)"
if d then print(d) end
```